# Does the Falmec Rangehood (F3MLD12S1IR1) have a fuse

Tags: range-hood

The Falmec F3MLD12S1IR1 Rangehood suddenly has no lights.  There is power at the override switch and the connections there are fine.

I downloaded the manuals and they don't mention anything about a fuse.  Does anyone know if it has a fuse and where it might be.

The solar installers finished today installing the battery today.  Indirectly they have triggered the issue.  But everything else is working, all circuit breakers are on.